# Include metric source when streaming metrics from cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, distributed-tracing

I'm streaming metrics to honeycomb following this docs: https://github.com/honeycombio/cloudformation-integrations/tree/main

When receiving metric, they don't seem to include they're source i.e. which lambda, SQS instances ...etc

Expected to see details about the metrics source as its the case on CloudWatch UI